# How can I extract the reason of the legal compensation from a court report?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, natural-language-processing

I'm working on a project (court-related). At a certain point, I have to extract the reason of the legal compensation. For instance, let's take these sentences (from a court report)

> Order mister X to pay EUR 5000 for compensation for unpaid wages

and

> To cover damages, mister X must pay EUR 4000 to mister Y

I want to make an algorithm that is able from this sentence to extract the motive of legal compensation. For the first sentence

> Order mister X to pay EUR 5000 for compensation for unpaid wages

the algorithm's output must be "compensation for unpaid wages" or "compensation unpaid wages ".

For the second sentence, the algorithm's output must be "cover damages". Output can be a string or a list of string, it doesn't matter.

As I'm not an NLP expert (but I have already worked on a project on sentiment analysis, so I know some stuff about NLP), and there are so many articles, I don't know where to start.

I'm working on French texts, but I can get away with working on English texts.

Comment: Maybe you can get away with using just regex and detect numbers followed by EUR or maybe detect `n  years in jail` phrase.